# Special Character & is getting printed as &amp;

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my `index.html.erb` page when data is queried from MSSQL it get displayed as 
`Me&amp;Mine`. I tried this:

```
$("#3").text("<%= escape_javascript(raw render(:partial => "var") %>");
```

but it doesn't work.

index.html.erb :

```
<%= link_to "Link", {:action => "AjaxView",:col => "colname"}, 
        :update => "Ajaxcall", :remote => true %>
<tr>
<td id="#3" style="height:25px">data displayed here</td>
```

Controller:

```
def AjaxView
  @vars= Var.find(:all,:conditions => { :varName=> "one" },:select=>(params[:col]))
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :layout=>false }
  end
end
```

AjaxView.js.erb:

```
 if ( @col.to_s == "colName") {
   $("#3").text("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "var") %>");
 }
 elsif ( @col.to_s == "colName1")
 {
   $("#2").text("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "var") %>");
 }
```

_var.html.erb:

```
<%= var.col1 %>
```

How can I display `Me&Mine` instead of `Me&amp;Mine`?

Comment: Are you sure you want & and not &amp;?  Does the Javascript work?  Also, look at your question, you may need to escape the ampersand in you question as &amp; and not &amp;amp&semi;.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried using [html_safe](http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe) on it?

Comment: This indeed is a helper wich can be found in the application_helper.rb file wich will render the "special chars" as html output I find this much cleaner than the "raw" method

Comment: @Michael Kohl exactly where you want me to place html_safe command, I tried $("#3").text("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "var") %>").html_safe but it didn't worked

Comment: @AmitVashistha You have to call it on the Ruby string that contains the special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Convert this:

```
$("#3").text("<%= escape_javascript(raw render(:partial => "var") %>");
```

to:

```
$("#3").html("<%= escape_javascript(raw render(:partial => "var") %>");
```

and it will work fine.

This is because when you are using "text" which is plain text without any formatting, so it is not able to render "&" and prints its raw form. But using HTML will render it with markup/formatting.